# What other logic gates can be added to the set {XOR} to form a universal set?

Tags: computer-science, hardware

I am having problem with the following question:

`The set {XOR} is not a complete set, that is, XOR is not a universal gate. Add another logic gate into the set to make the new set a complete set, and prove that it is complete.`

A `NOT` gate can be achieved through the use of `XOR` and a `And` gate can be represented through the a combination of a `NOT` gate and `XOR` gate.

I cannot figure out the second gate that I should use. Do I simply add an `OR` gate to the set because I feel that it is not answering the question.

Additionally, I would like to know if my understanding of a Universal Set is correct: A universal set should be able to represent {AND, OR, NOT}

Edit: It's not possible to create an `And` gate with `XOR` gate alone.

Comment: Right.  Well, more accurately, with a "universal set", you can produce any set of four outputs from the four pairs of inputs.  Adding OR will let you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create an AND gate (or an OR gate for that matter) with XOR alone, hence it is not a universal set.
XOR with AND is a universal set though - which means you can create any Boolean expression with this set.

You can find more info here:
https://cseweb.ucsd.edu//classes/sp14/cse140-b/slides/140-sp14-lec6.pdf

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did not consider the case where the input were all 0s'.